# Specific URL has 403 Forbidden status code

Tags: redirect, htaccess, server

I'm debugging a Belgian WP website: [slotenmakerbelgie.com](https://slotenmakerbelgie.com). The problem is that I get a forbidden status on a specific URL: [slotenmakerbelgie.com/error/](https://slotenmakerbelgie.com/error/) (with and without trailing slash at the end)

I really don't understand what's going on. I already have checked the following:

- **Temporary deleted `.htaccess`**
- **Temporary deactivated all plugins**
- **Checked empty folders**
- **Checked and deleted `wp_old_slug_redirect`**
- **Redirections**
- **WordPress settings / files / did an integrity scan** (no WP files are modified and uploaded a fresh WP install)

I'm really getting frustrated what the problem could be. My .htaccess file has just the default WP stuff:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

### And to clarify

This shouldn't be happening. It's not default behavior. I'm maintaining similar websites. These websites all have a custom 404 page with a WP plugin called [404page](https://wordpress.org/plugins/404page/)

There is no `error` folder! The rest of the website works, it's only this specific URL. I already did this: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-403-forbidden-error-in-wordpress/

I have also deactivated and deleted the [SuperPWA](https://wordpress.org/plugins/super-progressive-web-apps/) plugin. It's still a problem, therefore I can conclude this has nothing to do with a service worker, because currently there is none.

Comment: "with and without trailing slash at the end" - It would seem there is a 301 redirect to append the slash. The network traffic states that the 301 redirect and 403 response are both "from ServiceWorker".

Comment: @MrWhite This is what I first thought, just now I have deleted the SuperPWA plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/super-progressive-web-apps/ It's still a problem. It gives me headaches.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked and found that you are getting forbidden error only on this page slotenmakerbelgie.com/error. So maybe you are getting this error because there is folder name error (maybe hidden) and there is no permission to access that folder publicly.

Comment: Hi @Manntrix I checked all folders on my server. We are on a shared server / hosting.